# PHP - How can I test this class?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm just getting started with PHPUnit and I'm struggling on how to test certain features. For example, I've got the following class with loads the DotEnv library, and I'd like to test the following features...

1. Test the variables are loaded
2. Test it doesn't if the config is already cached
3. Test it throws an exception if a required variable is missing

But I'm struggling with the best way to do this `$app->configurationIsCached()` is managed elsewhere so blocks then rest of the class from executing.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Foundation\Bootstrap;

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Foundation\Core;

class LoadEnvironmentVariables
{


    /**
     * Any required variables.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $required = [
        'APP_URL',
        'DB_NAME',
        'DB_USER',
        'DB_PASS',
        'DB_HOST'
    ];


    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @param Core $app The application instance.
     */
    public function __construct(Core $app)
    {

        // If the configuration is cached, then we don't need DotEnv.
        if ($app->configurationIsCached()) {
            return;
        }

        // Load the DotEnv instance
        $this->load($app->get('paths.base'));
    }


    /**
     * Loads the .env file at the given path
     *
     * @param string $filePath The path to the .env file
     * @return void
     */
    public function load(string $filePath)
    {
        $dotEnv = Dotenv::create($filePath);
        $dotEnv->safeLoad();
        $dotEnv->required($this->required);
    }
}
```

Comment: As your class doesn't actually allow anything (except derived classes) to see the values loaded, you may have to derive a test class to allow you to check what is loaded.  But as for the rest, you can mock the `Core` class and make sure it gets called with `configurationIsCached()` and as for the required - create a test .env file with some values missing and check an exception is thrown.  Without the code for these classes, it is difficult to write and test something to ensure it reflects the actual code you are using.

Comment: I suggest the [vfsStream](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream) to mock file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your code getting tied up on the `$app->configurationIsCached()`:**

Use something like [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/index.html) to create a mock of your `Core` class you're passing in as `$app` to your class. You can then mock `configurationIsCached()`, having it return whatever is needed to route your class through to the early return or the call to your `load()` method.